# Hibernate, properties changes not tracked

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-webflow

I'am writting a web application with spring webflow 2.4 and hibernate 4.3.
I have a problem with changes made on the entities after calling persist(). Those changes are not tracked and even a calling saveOrUpdate just before the end of the flow doesn't help (and should be useless anyway).

Hib config

```
<bean id="oracleDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="${db.oracle.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${db.oracle.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${db.oracle.password}" />
    </bean>

<bean id="oracleSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDataSource" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="be.core.dao.interceptor.AuditInterceptor"/>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
            hibernate.default_schema=
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <value>domain</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACT")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "ACT_SEQ", sequenceName = "ACT_SEQ")
public class Act extends BaseEntity<Long> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -731258565201165908L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ACT_SEQ")
    @Column(name="ACTNUM")
    private Long id;

    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="SOCNUM")
    private Enterprise enterprise;

    @DateFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="ACTEDATE")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "ACTE", nullable = false, length = 12)
    private String actRef;
```

Code in the flow controller :

```
public Act createBaseAct(Enterprise enterprise, User user) {
        Act act = new Act(enterprise);
        act.setWho(user.getWho());
        act.setSource(SOURCE);
        actDao.persist(act);
        return act;
    }
```

When calling persist(), the id is correctly generated using the declared sequence.

At the end of the flow, the commit is executed but result in error because the property actRef is set after the persist() and is not tracked :

```
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.SQL - insert into ACT (DATCRE, MAJD, version, QUI, ACTE, ACTEDATE, SOCNUM, ACTENOPG, ACTELNG, ACTEDRPG, ACTESRC, ACTENUM) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
TRACE: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl - Registering statement [oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement@181496]TRACE: org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - Dehydrating entity: [domain.Act#236871950]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [DATE] - [Mon Aug 18 09:35:11 CEST 2014]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [DATE] - [Mon Aug 18 09:35:11 CEST 2014]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [0]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [QP]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [6] as [DATE] - [Mon Aug 18 09:35:11 CEST 2014]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [7] as [BIGINT] - [404371]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [8] as [INTEGER] - [1]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [9] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [10] as [INTEGER] - [1]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [11] as [VARCHAR] - [6010]
    TRACE: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [12] as [BIGINT] - [236871950]
    DEBUG: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute statement [n/a]
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ACT"."ACTE")
```

Some properties are set further in the flow execution but even if i set the property directly after the persist(), it's not tracked...

I don't see what i m doing wrong here, the entity should be managed. Does anyone have a hint on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i know it's because of the not-null constraint, that's very clear. What i figured is that hibernate will do an insert then an update with the changes done after the persist... That's why it's an SQL exception. I was hoping that hibernate would resolve the changes done on the entity before creating the insert statement. Apparently there is no way to enforce that except persisting at the very end of the flow.
The problem is that i need the generate the id as soon as possible because it's used as soft reference in other entities created during the same flow.

My solution was to generate id manually and persist at the very end of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

> When calling persist(), the id is correctly generated using the
>   declared sequence.

It is not possible because you have not_null constraint on `ACTE` field.

See the last line in the STrace.
The error correctly states that `cannot insert NULL into ("ACT"."ACTE")`

You will have to set value in `actRef` before you `persist()` the object.

Comment: The id is generated, it is possible. Constraints are only checked at commit